# Need a button next to the a heading in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a submit button in the end of the line of my heding. Somehow the button keeps on moving to the next line. I have tried a bunch of things, but nothing proved out to be useful. It be nice if you help me. I have the link to the picture which shows the way i want the page to look after I move the button. I am going to post the code below here. Thanks in advance.

This is the link to the picture that i want it to look it. 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ctZagMO.png]

```
<form:form commandName="address" method="POST">
    <div class="form">              
            <h5>Address:</h5></td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">                
            <div>
                <form>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2nd Name Line:</td>
                            <td><form:input path="secondNameLine" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
```

Comment: Your structure is inherently wrong. There is no `<table>` around the row that contain the header and the submit button. Try using floats instead.

Comment: Don't markup a form using a table, look up the `<fieldset>` and `<label>` tags.

Comment: I am not using plain html, I am using spring that takes care of the Head and title section. All i need to write is the body section. I posted the code that i thought was important. Btw I am using Spring Form tag lib here

Comment: The above code is very "strange". Here's why: First of all, there is no `<table>` tag to start the first table (goes directly to `<tr>`). Then you have a `<form>` in another `<form>`, and a second `<table>` in your first `<table>`

Comment: Did any of the solutions help? Please select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

An html table is a pretty strict layout element.
You can't have a `<div>` in the table markup like you have there.  You need the following structure:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div> and content in here </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a starting tag for your table. Add `<table>` before your first `<tr>` tag.

View a working version of what you want here:
http://jsfiddle.net/J9PtN/

As requested, the submit button is next to the address field.